# Count frequency of each row in an array using Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

I have this huge array. I extracted the unique rows in a separate array. Now I would like to create a vector in which to store the occurrences of each unique row. How could I do that? Tried using histc. I found about `tabulate`, but only works on vectors.

```
x=[62   29  64
    63  32  61
    63  32  61
    63  32  61
    63  31  62
    62  29  64
    62  29  64
    65  29  60
    62  29  64
    63  32  61
    63  32  61
    63  29  62
    63  32  61
    62  29  64
    ];

uA=unique(x)
[row, count] = histc(x,unique(x,'rows'))
```

I get the following error: `Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.` Also encountered this error in a couple of other attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `unique` this way -

```
[unique_rows,~,ind] = unique(x,'rows')
counts = histc(ind,unique(ind))
```

`unqiue_rows` and `counts` would be the outputs you might be interested in.

With your given data it yields -

```
unique_rows =
    62    29    64
    63    29    62
    63    31    62
    63    32    61
    65    29    60
counts =
     5
     1
     1
     6
     1
```

**Bonus:** You can improve on performance by avoiding the second use of `unique` this way -

```
counts = histc(ind,1:max(ind));
```

Comment: Oh, I did try unique this way, but I could not figure out what `~` and especially `ind=[ 1  4   4   4   3   1   1   5   1   4   4   2   4   1  ]` represented and I have abandoned the idea.

Comment: @TanatosDaniel If you didn't get it yet, `~` means `skip the output`. That `ind` just labels the rows of `x` according to their uniqueness.

Comment: I thought `~` means something like that. The information from mathworks about `unique` function and its parameters didn't seem too clear, at least not for me. I wouldn't have known what `ind` represent if it weren't for you. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to add the `ind` column to the `unique_rows` like this: `unique_row_counts[unique_rows counts unique(ind)]`? I tried it on the matrix above and seems to work.

Comment: @TanatosDaniel I am not sure where does that `unique_row_counts` come from.